# join data frame based on date ranges not exact values

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`. I want to join these dataframes on `id` and `date` so that each observation in `df2` is mapped to `df1` based on date range. There are no exact matches on `id` and `date`, so I have to infer the correct match based on where the `date` in `df2` falls relative to the `date` in `df1` for each `id`. Let's get generate the data for a toy example.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                  date = lubridate::date(c("2020-01-01",
                                           "2020-03-01",
                                           "2020-05-01",
                                         
                                           "2020-02-01",
                                           "2020-04-01",
                                           "2020-06-01")),
                  thing1 = c("a", "b", "c", 
                             "a", "b", "c"))

df2 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                  date = lubridate::date(c("2020-01-05",
                                           "2020-02-20",
                                           "2020-03-05",
                                           "2020-03-10",
                                           "2020-05-05",
                                           
                                           "2020-02-05",
                                           "2020-02-10",
                                           "2020-04-05",
                                           "2020-04-10",
                                           "2020-06-05")),
                  thing2 = c("v", "w", "x", "y", "z", 
                             "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"))

df1
#  id       date thing1
#1  1 2020-01-01      a
#2  1 2020-03-01      b
#3  1 2020-05-01      c
#4  2 2020-02-01      a
#5  2 2020-04-01      b
#6  2 2020-06-01      c

df2
#   id       date thing2
#1   1 2020-01-05      v
#2   1 2020-02-20      w
#3   1 2020-03-05      x
#4   1 2020-03-10      y
#5   1 2020-05-05      z
#6   2 2020-02-05      v
#7   2 2020-02-10      w
#8   2 2020-04-05      x
#9   2 2020-04-10      y
#10  2 2020-06-05      z
```

Here's what I want:

```
want <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), date = structure(c(18266, 
18312, 18326, 18331, 18387, 18297, 18302, 18357, 18362, 18418
), class = "Date"), thing2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("v", "w", "x", "y", "z"), class = "factor"), 
    thing1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
want
#   id       date thing2 thing1
#1   1 2020-01-05      v      a
#2   1 2020-02-20      w      a
#3   1 2020-03-05      x      b
#4   1 2020-03-10      y      b
#5   1 2020-05-05      z      c
#6   2 2020-02-05      v      a
#7   2 2020-02-10      w      a
#8   2 2020-04-05      x      b
#9   2 2020-04-10      y      b
#10  2 2020-06-05      z      c
```

In this example, `id==1` on `2020-02-20` in `df2` maps to `thing1==a` because "a" is the reigning value for `id==1` between the first value "2020-01-01" and the second value "2020-03-01".

**Problem 1:** I can get almost there by using `complete()` on `df1` to fill in all of the missing dates by `id` and then join with `df2`. One problem is that there is no exact match for dates that fall out of the min/max range for each `id`. For instance, `id==1` on "2020-05-05" should map to a value of "c" because it falls after "2020-05-01" in `df1`, but there's no match in the completed/joined dataframe.

```
df1_ <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  complete(id, date = seq.Date(min(date), max(date), by="day")) %>% 
  fill(thing1)

df1_df2 <- df2 %>%
  left_join(df1_, by=c("id", "date"))

df1_df2 
#   id       date thing2 thing1
#1   1 2020-01-05      v      a
#2   1 2020-02-20      w      a
#3   1 2020-03-05      x      b
#4   1 2020-03-10      y      b
#5   1 2020-05-05      z   <NA>
#6   2 2020-02-05      v      a
#7   2 2020-02-10      w      a
#8   2 2020-04-05      x      b
#9   2 2020-04-10      y      b
#10  2 2020-06-05      z   <NA>
```

**Problem 2:** The bigger problem for me is that this approach does not scale. My real `df1` has several date observations each for >500k ids. Creating a complete dataframe by person between big data ranges creates millions of records quickly and takes too long.

How would you go about solving this problem more efficiently?

Comment: There are two ways in R to efficiently do joins on ranges (instead of equality): `data.table` supports it directly, and `dbplyr` supports it when the data is in a DBMS of some type (which includes local SQLite). I suggest you go with one of those, as trying to brute-force this is reinventing a wheel that is very difficult to get right.

Comment: Thanks, @r2evans. It's helpful to know that there are better approaches out there. I'll search for some good examples to follow. I don't know much about data.table.

Comment: It's a frequently requested feature for `dplyr` ([dplyr/#557](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/557) and [dplyr#2240](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2240)), though I have no idea on its timeline. If you're comfortable "enough" with SQL, you might consider temporarily moving data into a SQLite structure and using `dbplyr`, as it allows `sql_on="(x < y and ...)"` joins.

Comment: My example is actually in postgres, so `dbplyr` is possible. With this approach do I need to first calculate the "end" of each period. For instance, in `df1`, `id==1` has a value of "a" for "2020-01-1" and a value of "b" for the next obs, "2020-03-01". Do I need to create a `dateEnd` column to show that "a" applies to "2020-01-01" through "2020-02-29"?

Comment: You're going to need to find a way to widen that data (in `dplyr`/`dbplyr` or in SQL) so that each row contains a range. I *think* `tidyr::pivot_wider` might translate into `dbplyr`, though I have not attempted that. Your goal is to assign another column to each row that is the value of the next row's date, by group.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans. I added a `{dplyr}` solution for the toy example (it involves taking your suggestion to get a date range), but it is too expensive for my actual use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a demonstration of using `dbplyr` to affect non-equal joins. I'll use a temporary (in-memory) SQLite database, which has one side-effect of converting dates to numbers; this is both reversible (if you use SQLite) and should not be a factor for DBMSes that distinguish between `Date` and `numeric`.

Setup:

```r
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
# rename them in the db for unambiguity here in code
DBI::dbExecute(con, "drop table if exists table1")
DBI::dbExecute(con, "drop table if exists table2")
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
copy_to(con, df1, "table1")
copy_to(con, df2, "table2")
```

The work:

```r
tbl1 <- tbl(con, "table1")
tbl2 <- tbl(con, "table2")
tbl1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  transmute(id, date1 = date, date2 = lead(date - 1, default = 99999999), thing1) %>%
  left_join(tbl2, ., sql_on = "LHS.id = RHS.id and (RHS.date1 <= LHS.date and LHS.date < RHS.date2)") %>%
  select(-date1, -date2, -id.y) %>%
  rename(id = id.x) %>%
  collect()
# # A tibble: 10 x 4
#       id  date thing2 thing1
#    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr> 
#  1     1 18266 v      a     
#  2     1 18312 w      a     
#  3     1 18326 x      b     
#  4     1 18331 y      b     
#  5     1 18387 z      c     
#  6     2 18297 v      a     
#  7     2 18302 w      a     
#  8     2 18357 x      b     
#  9     2 18362 y      b     
# 10     2 18418 z      c
```

---

**Edit** using a postgres container.

```r
tbl1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  transmute(id, date1 = date, date2 = lead(date), thing1) %>%
  mutate(date2 = if_else(is.na(date2), as.Date("2099-01-01"), date2)) %>%
  left_join(tbl2, ., sql_on = '"LHS".id = "RHS".id and ("RHS".date1 <= "LHS".date and "LHS".date < "RHS".date2)') %>%
  select(-date1, -date2, -id.y) %>%
  rename(id = id.x) %>%
  collect()
# # A tibble: 10 x 4
#       id date       thing2 thing1
#    <dbl> <date>     <chr>  <chr> 
#  1     1 2020-01-05 v      a     
#  2     1 2020-02-20 w      a     
#  3     1 2020-03-05 x      b     
#  4     1 2020-03-10 y      b     
#  5     1 2020-05-05 z      c     
#  6     2 2020-02-05 v      a     
#  7     2 2020-02-10 w      a     
#  8     2 2020-04-05 x      b     
#  9     2 2020-04-10 y      b     
# 10     2 2020-06-05 z      c
```

Some of the problems I ran into with this:

- date-math is something I should have expected problems with, since most DBMSes have specific functions for date/time arithmetic, and I made no effort to address that (I was being lazy with SQLite's numeric date-alias); additionally, I don't know how to get `lead(..., default=)` working, so I trimmed the `lead(...)` call and added a `mutate`;
- postgres was taking issue with the fact that `dbplyr` identifier-quotes all of the tables name (e.g., `FROM "table" AS "LHS"`, yet my `sql_on` was using *un*quoted `LHS`; when I changed the `sql_on` to have quoted table names, things stopped breaking; you can see how this query pans out by replacing `collect()` with `show_query()`, showing the change from

  ```r
  ON (LHS.id = RHS.id and (RHS.date1 <= LHS.date and LHS.date < RHS.date2))
  ```

  to

  ```r
  ON ("LHS".id = "RHS".id and ("RHS".date1 <= "LHS".date and "LHS".date < "RHS".date2))
  ```

Comment: thanks @r2evans. i'm getting an error that the minus operator does not exist in `transmute()` so working there right now.

Comment: The use of `99999999` is a placeholder. Put something meaningful in there, meant to be "Infinity" in a sense. It will be null (`NA`) in the last row of each group, so it's important (unless you know that that group should never be matched). That might be throwing you off, mixing classes.

Comment: For instance, instead of `default=99999999`, consider removing `default=` and next add `filter(!is.na(date2))`, perhaps that also better meets your expectations of the logic of the join.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still getting "Error: Failed to prepare query: ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone - numeric" with the hint that "No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: Amazing, @r2evans. That works! And it's pretty fast. I didn't realize the difference could be so stark. A minor issue is that I had to rename a `variableName` to `variablename` to avoid an error "column LHS.variableName does not exist". I probably just need to learn how to get SQL to be ok with caps in column names.

Comment: Yeah, field case can be frustrating, some DBMSes don't care about case-sens, others are strict about it. Glad it works. (And yes, DBMSes tend to do this kind of operation pretty fast :-)

Answer (score 1):

A tip and a few links from @r2evans helped me get to a solution in `{dplyr}`. While this works for my toy example, I run out of vector memory for my real use case. I need to look into the `{dbplyr}` option. Tips appreciated.

First, get an end date column to make date ranges:

```
df1_ <-
  df1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(dateEnd = lead(date, 1),
         dateEnd = if_else(is.na(dateEnd), 
                           lubridate::date(Sys.Date()),
                           dateEnd))
```

Then use the `{fuzzyjoin}` package to join by date range.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
fj <- df2 %>%
  fuzzy_left_join(df1_, 
                  by = c("id" = "id",
                         "date" = "date",
                         "date" = "dateEnd"),
                  match_fun = list(`==`, `>=`, `<`)
                  ) %>%
  rename(id = id.x, date = date.x) %>%
  select(id, date, thing1, thing2)
```